# How do I check if redis is running before I start flask (and start it if it isn't)?

Tags: python, redis, flask

I am new to Flask and want to make sure the redis server is running and start it if it isn't. Here's what I have:

```
@app.before_first_request
def initialize():
  cmd = 'src/redis-cli ping'
  p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  out, err = p.communicate()
  #if out.startswith('Could not connect to Redis'): #start redis here
  if err is not None: raise Exception(err)
```

However, I get an error "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Is there an easier way to check if the redis server is running?

Comment: I would not take this approach. I'd make sure my Flask app and redis are deployed in a single container/rpm/whatever. It's not your Flask App's job to spin up redis.

Comment: can you be more specific? I'm new to flask

Comment: It's not a comment about Flask. It's a comment about the separation of responsibilities in a software environment. "Configuration is not part of the application", as Hynek says. Use puppet or chef or ansible or saltstack to deploy your app and all its dependencies. Make sure your app and dependencies are running with supervisord or similar.

Comment: And: make sure you know what all your dependencies are by running your application in a virtual environment that is populated by script only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12968704/538284) [ping](http://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#redis.StrictRedis.ping) cmd of redis:

```
import redis
from redis import ConnectionError
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger('redis')

rs = redis.Redis("localhost")
try:
    rs.ping()
except ConnectionError:
    logger.error("Redis isn't running. try `/etc/init.d/redis-server restart`")
    exit(0)
```

Sample Output:

```
ERROR:redis:Redis isn't running. try `/etc/init.d/redis-server restart`
```

Comment: and how do I start it if it isn't running? Also, should I put this in  the before_first_request function?

Comment: It's better to start it manually or by something similar to `Puppet` and not by flask application, the command of it added to output of log.

Comment: Do not use this code in `before_first_request` function, put this code in somewhere your flask application(`app = Flask()`) is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use some kind of a `supervision` like `supervisord` or `monit` they are designed to check if process, host, file and so on is doing it;s job, and if not,then restart it.

For example here is the config to check redis:

```
 check host redis with address <your_redis_host>
  if failed icmp type echo count 3 with timeout 3 seconds then alert
  if failed port 6379 with timeout 15 seconds then alert
```